# Getting No self-signed cert in chain error while using orapki wallet jks_to_pkcs12 -wallet

Tags: java, keystore

I got the CA signed certificates and tried to import into the Oracle Wallet Manager for OHS SSL. Private Key and certificate request is generated using open ssl and so we have to create the pkcs12 cert first using the below -

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -name myservercert -in selfsigned.crt -inkey server.key -out keystore.p12
```

After that i converted this to JKS using below -

```
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore mykeystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias myservercert
```

and then imported the Intermediate certs in the JKS. After that when i am trying to convert jks to pkcs12 again using -

```
mw_home\oracle_common\bin\orapki wallet jks_to_pkcs12 -wallet ./ -pwd "mypassword" -keystore ./mykeystore.jks -jkspwd "mypassword"
```

I am getting the error - `Exception : java.io.IOException: No self-signed cert in chain`.

We are not using any self-signed certificate so wondering from where we are getting this issue.

I tried using the p12 keystore that i created in the very first step but there is no certificate request or certificates getting displayed in Oracle Wallet.

Please suggest what is wrong I am doing or is there any best way to import certificates in Oracle Wallet.

Comment: If you 'are not using any self-signed certificate' why is the file in the first step called 'selfsigned.crt'?

Comment: I just copied and saved my CA signed cert with this name. Sorry for confusion. I was trying to use the command i found over the internet

Answer (score 0):

why did you use keytool to import intermediate certifcates and not orapki?

orapki wallet add -wallet  -cert trustedcerts.crt -trusted_cert

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother creating a JKS file.  Oracle wallets are valid PKCS12 files.  Just create a PEM file with full certificate chain (your private key, your cert, and the full certificate chain in a single file), then run

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certchain.pem -out ewallet.p12
```

The name 'ewallet.p12' is important.  That is Oracle's requirement.  Put this file in your wallet directory, then run

```
orapki wallet create -wallet . -pwd your_pass -auto_login
```

to create the cwallet.sso file.